# how to get user input with a prompt into a variable in a posix compliant way

Tags: shell-script, posix, read, shellcheck

```bsh
read -r -p "put an option: " option
echo $option
```

this works but shellcheck gives me:

```
In POSIX sh, read -p is undefined.
```

How to get user input with a prompt into a variable in a posix compliant way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use read without `-p`:

```
printf "put an option: " >&2
read -r option
printf '%s\n' "$option"
```

Comment: needs to call `printf` or `echo`? I mean, can't this be handled by `read` only? thanks

Comment: @testoflow It depends. Are you writing a portable script, meant to run in any POSIX shell, or are you targeting a specific shell? `shellcheck` gives you that warning when you target `sh`, but common implementations (e.g. `dash`, `busybox ash`) actually support prompting with `read -p`. It won't work, however, in `zsh` and, I think, in ksh88 and derivatives (and in the original Bourne shell).

Comment: @testoflow: You could use echo but [printf is better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).   As fra-san mentioned many, if not most systems would accept `-p` but if you want to be pure POSIX sh you can't use it.  If you know it wont be an issue you can ignore certain shellcheck rules.